# Dynamic Number of Reducers in Hadoop MR Application

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any means to set the number of reduce tasks once a job is submitted? For example if I need to collect English words based on start alphabet, I can directly set the number of reduce tasks as 26. But in case a scenario arises where I cannot pre determine the number of reducers required,is there any means to accomplish the requirement? Here the requirement is independent of the number of nodes on the cluster, it just depends on the key being processed. Say for example, the number of reducers is to increment by one each time a new key is met. 
Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any means to set the number of reduce tasks once a job is submitted?

No

> For example if I need to collect English words based on start alphabet, I can directly set the number of reduce tasks as 26.

Even in the above scenario, you need not have 26 reducers, but only 1 reducer. The reduce function is called again and again for each key by the Hadoop framework. [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) can be used to write the words to different files based on the key/value pair (first alphabet).

The criteria for the number of reducers for the job should be the amount of data it's processing. Also, remember that the reducer taking the most time will determine the time for the completion of the job.

Comment: Not only to mention, that in the case of 26 reducers, each one will get a single character from the alphabet. The HashPartitioner could distribute two characters two a single reducer.

Comment: @ Thomas : I was not mentioning about hashpartitioner. I was mentioning about custom partitioner. I did not understand your comment. Any way , what I said is to divert each <key,value> to reducers based on charAt(0) of key. May be I took your comment in a wrong sense.